# Evaluate JavaScript document.write from external file in a div block

Tags: javascript

I know this question sounds rather confusing, yet let's see if I can explain this right:

### What?

I plan on dynamically loading content from outer `.js` files which run `document.write`. I've successfully loaded file content via *web.py*, yet I wish I could place everything that `.js` file `document.write`s inside an HTML `div` element.

### How?

I have an outer `.js` file which contains a couple of `document.write` calls. As the URL from which I get this `.js` file is changeable, instead of adding a `<script src>` tag to my `div` element, I decided to `eval()` the contents of that script.

I already have the contents of that file, and managed to `eval()` it with no problem at all. Thing is, when I call `eval()` from a `<script>` tag inside the `div` element, everything goes fine: Every content of the `document.write` calls is inserted right where I want it to (inside the `div` element).

Yet I can't seem to successfully do what I want. The following call: `document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = eval(theContents);`
in a script tag in a random location at my document will cause the whole document to be replaced by the arguments of the outer `document.write` calls, not only the `div` element. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. I am kinda surprised even to see all the three stupid things to do ( `document.write` , `eval` and `innerHTML` ) in a single post.

Comment: @tereško I appreciate the sincerity of the comment (mainly because I'm a JavaScript noob), yet I'm willing to learn from my mistakes, which means: Do you actually have a suggestion on how to make this non-eye-burning code?

Comment: in that case, you should explain **what** are you trying to accomplish , instead of **how**.

Comment: I am trying to get content from a `.js` file and put whatever it writes with `document.write` (not a good start I know...) inside a `div` element. Note: I'm writing an web.py app and I'm using it to get contents from that file.

Comment: That is still "how". Why do you need external JS file willed with `document.write` statements? Are you trying to dynamically load content into the application ?

Comment: Yes. The js files are third-party. :(

Comment: Is that external JS file creating a widget , or providing a static content , or adding some behavior to your page ?

Comment: It `document.write`s HTML content. Something that if just `eval()`uated fills in the whole document with that content.

Comment: Then you should request that external JS file on the python's side, extract the html from that mess, and either put it directly inside you HTML output, or load using XHR. If you load the external content using XHR, then you will be able to update the data too, if content of that JS file changes.

Comment: One thing that may help clarify matters is sample content for `theContents`. As for the question focusing too much on a specific solution rather than the overall problem, it's also known as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider monkey patching `document.write` to do something else instead:

```
var parts = [];

var oldDw = document.write;
document.write = function(str){
    parts.push(str);
}

//calls to document.write do different things now

document.write = oldDw;
myDiv.innerHTML = parts.join('');
```

Comment: +1 for the concept, but i dont think you should overwrite document.write(); either way its a good solution

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can suggest to you is to replace all document.write occurences by another function using replace(). This function would store argument into an output reusable string.

I didn't test it, but that should do the job :

```
var ouputString = ""

function myRedirectFunction(arg) {
    outputString += arg
}

code = code.replace("document.write(", "myRedirectFunction(");
```

After that you can call your eval function.